# Front audio jack not working

Tags: sound, jack

I dual booted ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 last week.
I am not getting any audio output from the front panel audio jack on my desktop in ubuntu , although I am getting it on windows 7.
REAR connected speakers are working fine in both windows and ubuntu.
I am new in this , please help!